# Removing Identity Column from SaveChanges in Database First Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I've got a SQL Server table, Organization, which has a uniqueidentifier as a PK. The client has asked for a identity column to be added as a "friendly id".

```
Organization organization = _db.Organizations.Find(organizationSource.UId);
_db.Entry(organization).CurrentValues.SetValues(organizationSource);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

now returns "Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported."

Is there a way to mark the identity column so database first EF won't update it, short of changing it to a PK which would affect many other pieces?

Comment: Is the property mapped as [Computed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.7)?

Comment: EF is generating the class from the database table. It's set StoreGeneratedPattern as Identity.

Comment: Then set is as computed.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an attribute you can use. But I'm not aware of it. As a work around, could you set the organization objects properties individually?

```cs
Organization organization = _db.Organizations.Find(organizationSource.UId);
_db.Entry(organization).Property(a => a.MyProperty1).CurrentValue = organizationSource.MyProperty1;
_db.Entry(organization).Property(a => a.MyProperty2).CurrentValue = organizationSource.MyProperty2;
// and so on for all properties except the primary key and the identity property
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Or, another option might be to remove your identity property from `organizationSource` class definition (assuming you have control of the organizationSource class).

Comment: I could set properties manually but I'm not looking forward to that as there are many properties and many tables where this kind of change has been requested.  I guess I could map organizationSource to a new class which doesn't have the identity property using AutoMapper but that would mean maintaining two classes.

Comment: @NeilN then maybe use reflection to loop through the properties, excluding the identity one? Although, using reflection would be a last resort. Or ... have your Organization inherit your OrganizationSource class, with your Organization class having the additional identity property. Bit easier to maintain ... but still two classes. Hopefully someone finds a way to do it using attributes. Might be worth adding your Organization class definition to your question.